# problem with edubuntu on ubuntu 16.04LTS remove educational desktop

Tags: gnome, 16.04, uninstall, software-uninstall, edubuntu

I installed edubuntu desktop educational desktop from terminal on ubuntu 16.04 by command

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux gnome-mplayer edubuntu-desktop edubuntu-artwork edubuntu-docs edubuntu-fonts edubuntu-menueditor'
```

but it creates problem on my laptop so I want to uninstall it completely so I tried to uninstall it by following command lines

```
sudo apt-get remove edubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove edubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get purge edubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove edubuntu-desktop
```

but educational desktop edubuntu is still working on my ubuntu 16.04 so please suggest a way to completely get rid of this educational desktop

Comment: please reply fast

Comment: edubuntu removed by below  command but dash and desktop skin or colour or background colour whatever it is said is still black earlier it was transparent kind and now also it takes time to start up like edubuntu when switching on suggest something

Answer (score 0):

Run the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge edubuntu* 
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop # if you were previously running unity
sudo apt-get install gnome # if you were previously running gnome
```

Comment: edubuntu removed by above command but dash and desktop skin or colour or background colour whatever it is said is still black earlier it was transparent kind and now also it takes time to start up like edubuntu when switching on suggest something

Comment: please reply fast

Comment: I am thinking about it.